# Is it possible to get instanceName in userData when create multiple AWS Lightsail instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I use python api `boto3` to manage the creation of Lightsail instance, and link the nodes created to salt-master, here is part of the code:

```
boot_script='''
curl -L https://bootstrap.saltstack.com -o install_salt.sh
sh install_salt.sh -P
sed -i 's/#master: salt/master: salt.my-domain.com/' /etc/salt/minion
rm -f /etc/salt/minion_id
'''

def main(args):
    client = boto3.client('lightsail')
    client.create_instances(
        instanceNames=[
            'test-01',
            'test-02',
            'test-03',
        ],
        availabilityZone='eu-west-2a',
        blueprintId='amazon_linux_2017_03_1_1',
        bundleId='nano_1_0',
        userData=boot_script,
        keyPairName='salt_master'
    )
```

So, how can I set hostname with the value of its instanceName via userData? Or is there some other solution?

Thanks.